# Is there a way to open a contextmenu in SwiftUI with a „normal“ touch?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In the first Betas of Xcode 11 I have tried to create a dropdownmenu and found in beta 4 a very interesting new element: the contextmenu. I have implemented it to my view and it works fine. But I want to open it with a normal touch (like a button). Is there a way to open it immediatelly?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var Texte = "Push the Button"
    var body: some View {
        Text(self.Texte)
            .contextMenu {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.Texte = "Option 1"
                    }) {
                        Text("Select Option 1")
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        self.Texte = "Option 2"
                    }) {
                        Text("Select Option 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: “In iOS 14 and later, a button can display a pull-down menu that lists items or actions from which people can choose.” - https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/pull-down-menus/

Sounds like this should be possible now but I have yet to find a way to do so with SwiftUI.

Comment: Was looking at this, too. You’d have to dip into UIKit to get the UIMenu for now.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible now via [Menu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu) (iOS 14+)
Menus are covered in this [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10052/) at ~11:15.

Playground Example:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            // Other views
            Text("Example View 1")

            // Button, that when tapped shows 3 options
            Menu {
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    Label("Add", systemImage: "plus.circle")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "minus.circle")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil.circle")
                }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Answer (score -4):

I don't think this will be ever possible. I assume you should use a popover.

Comment: exact words you can say in comment, this seems not any answer!